# How to calculate average in SQL server database

Tags: sql-server

I have a database table with the following information:

```
Test Time
1   1.59
1   1.56
1   1.57
1   1.57
1   0.49
1   1.57
1   1.57
1   1.57
1   1.57
1   1.56
15  0.85
15  0.85
15  0.86
15  0.85
15  0.85
15  0.13
15  0.85
15  0.85
15  0.84
15  0.86
16  1.45
16  1.41
16  1.44
16  1.44
16  0.47
16  1.44
16  1.44
16  1.45
16  1.44
16  1.47
17  5.28
17  5.29
17  3.88
17  5.29
17  5.29
17  4.51
17  5.29
17  5.29
17  5.34
17  5.15
18  3.51
18  3.52
18  3.58
18  3.58
18  4.55
18  3.58
18  3.58
18  3.58
18  3.58
18  3.49
19  2.49
19  2.49
19  2.42
19  2.49
19  2.49
19  2.21
19  2.49
19  2.49
19  2.49
19  2.50
20  2.51
20  2.50
20  2.51
20  2.51
20  1.84
20  2.51
20  2.51
20  2.46
20  2.51
20  2.51
21  2.18
21  2.23
21  2.18
21  2.18
21  2.18
21  1.79
21  2.18
21  2.18
21  2.20
21  2.20
22  0.72
22  0.71
22  0.69
22  0.69
22  0.11
22  0.69
22  0.69
22  0.71
22  0.69
22  0.69
23  133.53
23  133.53
23  133.45
23  133.40
23  133.53
23  118.98
23  133.53
23  133.53
23  132.38
23  133.64
24  1.05
24  1.03
24  1.05
24  1.05
24  0.13
24  1.05
24  1.05
24  1.05
24  1.05
24  1.06
25  2.35
25  2.35
25  2.36
25  2.36
25  2.35
25  0.51
25  2.35
25  2.35
25  2.36
25  2.38
26  0.81
26  0.80
26  0.81
26  0.81
26  0.13
26  0.81
26  0.81
26  0.81
26  0.81
26  0.81
27  15.34
27  15.34
27  15.35
27  15.19
27  15.34
27  14.53
27  15.34
27  15.34
27  15.12
27  15.06
28  1.01
28  1.00
28  0.99
28  0.99
28  0.38
28  0.99
28  1.01
28  0.99
28  0.99
28  0.99
29  0.99
29  0.99
29  0.99
29  1.01
29  0.99
29  0.42
29  0.99
29  0.99
29  1.00
29  1.02
30  0.99
30  0.97
30  0.97
30  0.97
30  0.37
30  0.97
30  0.99
30  0.97
30  0.97
30  0.98
31  21.76
31  21.76
31  21.76
31  21.51
31  21.76
31  21.76
31  23.72
31  21.76
31  21.23
31  21.30
32  39.83
32  39.99
32  40.75
32  46.50
32  40.75
32  40.75
32  41.34
32  40.75
32  40.75
32  40.75
33  3.60
33  3.60
33  3.60
33  3.44
33  3.60
33  3.60
33  2.86
33  3.60
33  3.53
33  3.53
34  61.21
34  62.01
34  61.98
34  61.93
34  61.98
34  61.98
34  64.00
34  61.98
34  61.98
34  62.03
35  4.79
35  4.79
35  4.78
35  4.79
35  4.79
35  4.79
35  8.66
35  4.79
35  4.76
35  4.79
36  1.14
36  1.15
36  0.89
36  0.39
36  0.89
36  0.89
36  0.89
36  0.91
36  0.89
36  0.89
37  0.69
37  0.69
37  0.71
37  0.74
37  0.69
37  0.69
37  0.12
37  0.69
37  0.68
37  0.70
38  1.10
38  1.09
38  1.09
38  0.55
38  1.09
38  1.09
38  1.09
38  1.10
38  1.09
38  1.09
39  1.67
39  1.67
39  1.68
39  1.65
39  1.67
39  1.67
39  0.23
39  1.67
39  1.61
39  1.70
40  1.92
40  1.91
40  1.89
40  0.69
40  1.89
40  1.89
40  1.90
40  1.93
40  1.89
40  1.89
41  12.03
41  12.03
41  12.20
41  11.93
41  12.03
41  12.03
41  3.96
41  12.03
41  11.96
41  12.20
42  2.16
42  2.17
42  2.09
42  1.33
42  2.09
42  2.09
42  2.09
42  2.09
42  2.09
42  2.10
43  27.22
43  27.18
43  27.18
43  27.37
43  27.18
43  27.18
43  27.18
43  20.92
43  26.64
43  27.45
44  21.51
44  20.76
44  8.70
44  21.15
44  21.15
44  21.15
44  21.18
44  21.24
44  21.15
44  21.15
45  17.22
45  17.22
45  17.17
45  17.20
45  17.22
45  17.22
45  17.22
45  14.74
45  16.99
45  16.99
46  15.52
46  14.91
46  25.94
46  15.39
46  15.39
46  15.77
46  15.92
46  15.39
46  15.39
46  15.39
47  8.10
47  8.10
47  8.10
47  7.78
47  8.10
47  8.10
47  8.10
47  7.38
47  7.98
47  8.02
48  8.96
48  8.90
48  8.33
48  9.08
48  9.08
48  9.08
48  9.08
48  8.86
48  9.08
48  9.08
49  3.94
49  3.94
49  3.91
49  3.94
49  3.94
49  3.94
49  3.94
49  1.35
49  3.90
49  3.94
50  0.78
50  0.76
50  0.18
50  0.76
50  0.76
50  0.76
50  0.77
50  0.76
50  0.76
50  0.76
51  1.28
51  1.28
51  1.28
51  1.28
51  1.28
51  1.28
51  0.46
51  1.28
51  1.28
51  1.31
52  7.89
52  7.88
52  7.95
52  7.25
52  7.95
52  7.96
52  7.63
52  7.95
52  7.95
52  7.95
53  16.90
53  16.90
53  16.90
53  15.46
53  17.14
53  16.90
53  14.44
53  16.90
53  16.12
53  15.39
54  1.17
54  1.16
54  1.14
54  0.16
54  1.14
54  1.14
54  1.18
54  1.14
54  1.14
54  1.14
55  0.94
55  0.94
55  0.94
55  0.95
55  0.94
55  0.94
55  0.22
55  0.94
55  0.94
55  0.95
56  2.35
56  2.31
56  3.01
56  1.31
56  3.01
56  3.00
56  3.09
56  3.01
56  3.01
56  3.01
57  2.62
57  2.62
57  2.62
57  2.65
57  2.62
57  2.62
57  1.21
57  2.62
57  1.94
57  1.95
58  3.21
58  3.18
58  3.18
58  2.61
58  3.18
58  3.17
58  3.21
58  3.18
58  3.18
58  3.18
59  2.31
59  2.31
59  2.31
59  2.38
59  2.31
59  2.31
59  1.04
59  2.31
59  1.64
59  1.65
60  3.95
60  3.93
60  3.95
60  3.08
60  3.95
60  3.95
60  3.96
60  3.95
60  3.95
60  3.95
61  3.18
61  3.18
61  3.18
61  3.21
61  3.18
61  3.18
61  2.61
61  3.18
61  3.19
61  3.21
62  0.88
62  0.87
62  0.23
62  0.87
62  0.87
62  0.87
62  0.88
62  0.87
62  0.87
62  0.87
63  0.85
63  0.85
63  0.85
63  0.86
63  0.85
63  0.85
63  0.85
63  0.18
63  0.86
63  0.86
64  0.75
64  0.75
64  0.14
64  0.74
64  0.74
64  0.74
64  0.75
64  0.74
64  0.74
64  0.74
65  0.75
65  0.75
65  0.75
65  0.76
65  0.75
65  0.75
65  0.75
65  0.14
65  0.75
65  0.76
67  0.72
67  0.71
67  0.13
67  0.71
67  0.71
67  0.71
67  0.72
67  0.71
67  0.71
67  0.71
68  1.46
68  1.46
68  1.46
68  1.47
68  1.46
68  1.46
68  1.46
68  1.00
68  1.46
68  1.47
69  6.15
69  6.08
69  2.70
69  6.18
69  6.18
69  6.18
69  6.01
69  6.18
69  6.18
69  6.18
70  1.75
70  1.75
70  1.75
70  1.77
70  1.74
70  1.75
70  1.75
70  0.22
70  1.74
70  1.78
71  0.74
71  0.73
71  0.12
71  0.73
71  0.73
71  0.73
71  0.75
71  0.73
71  0.73
71  0.73
72  0.74
72  0.74
72  0.74
72  0.75
72  0.74
72  0.74
72  0.74
72  0.11
72  0.74
72  0.74
73  0.68
73  0.68
73  0.15
73  0.67
73  0.67
73  0.67
73  0.69
73  0.67
73  0.67
73  0.67
74  0.71
74  0.71
74  0.71
74  0.72
74  0.71
74  0.71
74  0.71
74  0.12
74  0.71
74  0.71
75  1.71
75  1.68
75  0.87
75  1.68
75  1.68
75  1.68
75  1.71
75  1.68
75  1.68
75  1.68
76  0.86
76  0.86
76  0.86
76  0.88
76  0.86
76  0.86
76  0.86
76  0.13
76  0.87
76  0.87
77  23.15
77  22.03
77  10.40
77  22.81
77  22.81
77  22.69
77  22.65
77  22.81
77  22.81
77  22.81
78  22.65
78  22.65
78  22.65
78  22.99
78  22.70
78  22.65
78  22.65
78  10.34
78  22.78
78  22.98
79  30.96
79  30.23
79  18.67
79  30.34
79  30.34
79  30.71
79  30.50
79  30.34
79  30.34
79  30.34
80  1.17
80  1.17
80  1.17
80  1.16
80  1.18
80  1.17
80  1.17
80  0.17
80  1.17
80  1.17
81  2.17
81  2.06
81  0.32
81  2.14
81  2.14
81  2.14
81  2.15
81  2.14
81  2.14
81  2.14
82  0.68
82  0.68
82  0.68
82  0.69
82  0.68
82  0.68
82  0.68
82  0.11
82  0.68
82  0.69
83  0.90
83  0.89
83  0.14
83  0.90
83  0.90
83  0.90
83  0.91
83  0.90
83  0.90
83  0.90
84  0.84
84  0.84
84  0.84
84  0.85
84  0.84
84  0.84
84  0.84
84  0.12
84  0.84
84  0.84
85  1.82
85  1.86
85  0.36
85  1.87
85  1.87
85  1.87
85  1.86
85  1.87
85  1.87
85  1.87
86  31.20
86  31.13
86  31.20
86  31.20
86  15.70
86  31.20
86  31.11
86  31.34
86  30.98
86  31.20
87  22.92
87  23.66
87  23.64
87  23.33
87  22.92
87  11.26
87  22.92
87  22.92
87  22.91
87  22.92
88  6.14
88  6.16
88  6.14
88  6.14
88  6.14
88  6.13
88  5.34
88  6.18
88  6.36
88  6.14
89  8.98
89  9.33
89  9.21
89  6.32
89  8.86
89  8.98
89  8.98
89  8.98
89  8.96
89  8.98
90  8.12
90  8.27
90  8.12
90  8.12
90  8.10
90  8.12
90  8.12
90  8.00
90  5.93
90  8.17
91  34.22
91  33.89
91  33.65
91  21.09
91  33.78
91  33.65
91  33.65
91  33.65
91  33.64
91  33.65
92  2.29
92  2.31
92  2.29
92  2.29
92  2.29
92  2.30
92  0.64
92  2.29
92  2.28
92  2.36
93  1.28
93  1.26
93  1.25
93  0.15
93  1.22
93  1.25
93  1.25
93  1.25
93  1.25
93  1.25
94  0.70
94  0.70
94  0.70
94  0.70
94  0.70
94  0.70
94  0.12
94  0.70
94  0.71
94  0.71
95  0.98
95  0.97
95  0.99
95  0.12
95  0.98
95  0.99
95  0.99
95  0.99
95  0.98
95  0.99
96  3.58
96  3.57
96  3.58
96  3.58
96  3.58
96  3.54
96  0.91
96  3.58
96  3.57
96  3.55
97  8.28
97  8.24
97  8.29
97  13.93
97  8.35
97  8.29
97  8.29
97  8.29
97  8.32
97  8.29
98  8.16
98  8.15
98  8.16
98  8.16
98  8.16
98  8.10
98  11.85
98  8.16
98  8.12
98  8.13
99  7.67
99  7.70
99  7.72
99  7.48
99  7.67
99  7.72
99  7.72
99  7.72
99  7.72
99  7.72
100 23.82
100 23.82
100 23.80
100 23.82
100 23.82
100 24.32
100 11.11
100 23.82
100 24.68
100 25.04
101 20.06
101 19.58
101 19.28
101 6.31
101 19.60
101 19.28
101 19.28
101 19.45
101 19.28
101 19.28
102 2.45
102 2.45
102 2.46
102 2.45
102 2.45
102 2.51
102 1.06
102 2.45
102 2.47
102 2.55
103 1.20
103 1.24
103 1.22
103 0.77
103 1.21
103 1.22
103 1.22
103 1.22
103 1.22
103 1.22
104 343.20
104 343.20
104 343.80
104 343.20
104 343.20
104 340.98
104 476.10
104 343.20
104 343.71
105 1.79
105 1.78
105 1.78
105 0.58
105 0.33
105 1.81
105 1.78
105 1.78
105 1.77
105 1.78
106 13.22
106 13.21
106 13.22
106 13.22
106 13.13
106 12.05
106 12.01
106 13.22
106 13.22
106 15.93
108 7.53
108 6.60
108 6.60
108 5.60
108 5.62
108 6.53
108 6.60
108 6.60
108 6.60
108 6.60
109 5.26
109 5.27
109 5.26
109 5.26
109 5.24
109 4.26
109 4.24
109 5.26
109 5.26
109 6.22
110 7.48
110 6.59
110 6.59
110 5.60
110 5.61
110 6.54
110 6.59
110 6.59
110 6.59
110 6.59
111 5.27
111 5.28
111 5.27
111 5.27
111 5.24
111 4.25
111 4.25
111 5.27
111 6.25
111 5.27
112 0.72
112 0.71
112 0.71
112 0.14
112 0.14
112 0.71
112 0.71
112 0.71
112 0.71
112 0.71
113 0.73
113 0.73
113 0.73
113 0.73
113 0.73
113 0.16
113 0.21
113 0.73
113 0.73
113 0.74
114 0.71
114 0.70
114 0.70
114 0.12
114 0.12
114 0.70
114 0.70
114 0.70
114 0.70
114 0.70
115 0.97
115 0.97
115 0.97
115 0.97
115 0.98
115 0.26
115 0.27
115 0.97
115 0.97
115 0.99
116 0.91
116 0.91
116 0.91
116 0.18
116 0.18
116 0.91
116 0.91
116 0.91
116 0.91
116 0.91
117 0.86
117 0.86
117 0.86
117 0.86
117 0.85
117 0.12
117 0.12
117 0.86
117 0.86
117 0.85
118 3.16
118 3.15
118 3.15
118 0.85
118 0.79
118 3.20
118 3.15
118 3.15
118 3.14
118 3.15
119 5.78
119 5.78
119 5.78
119 5.78
119 5.75
119 5.08
119 5.16
119 5.78
119 5.78
119 7.66
120 2.91
120 2.97
120 2.97
120 2.21
120 2.22
120 2.87
120 2.97
120 2.97
120 2.97
120 2.97
121 1.15
121 1.16
121 1.16
121 1.16
121 1.16
121 1.16
121 1.15
121 0.52
121 0.54
121 1.16
```

These test iterate or runs ten times so I want to create a stored procedure or function that calculate the average time for each test. How can I do that in T-sql?

Here is my code so far:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('Test_CalculateAverageRunTime') IS NOT NULL)
        DROP PROCEDURE Test_CalculateAverageRunTime
    GO

        CREATE PROCEDURE Test_CalculateAverageRunTime
        (       
            @Test varchar(50) = NULL
        )      
    AS
    BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON     

            SELECT   test,  AVG(time) as AverageRunTime
            FROM Table1  t
            WHERE (@Test IS NULL OR Test = @Test)


    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    END
    GO
```

Seems like am lost entirely and am not good in writing store procedures. Anyone who can help?

Comment: "Group by test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('Test_CalculateAverageRunTime') IS NOT NULL)
        DROP PROCEDURE Test_CalculateAverageRunTime
    GO

        CREATE PROCEDURE Test_CalculateAverageRunTime
        (       
            @Test varchar(50) = NULL
        )      
    AS
    BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON     

            SELECT   test,  AVG(time) as AverageRunTime
            FROM Table1  t
            WHERE (@Test IS NULL OR Test = @Test)
            group by test


    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    END
    GO
```